# rspec controller spec for js request

Tags: testing, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

In my controller specs everything works fine (update action, edit action, etc. also via js request), except the create action. For some reason it doesn't change the `Task.count`, but the http response is `200`.

There are no other callbacks and in dev ENV it saves the task in the db. This factory passes in model spec. I also tried to comment out the `Notification.create`, `TaskCreatorJob` and `Conversation.create..`, but didn't help. In my other controller specs the `expect { create_action }.to change{Class.count}.by(1)` works properly.

What did I miss?

conroller

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.assigner_id = current_user.id
  if @task.save
    Notification.create(recipient_id: @task.executor_id, sender_id: current_user.id, notifiable: @task, action: "assigned")
    TaskCreatorJob.perform_later(@task, @task.executor, @task.assigner)
    Conversation.create_or_find_conversation(@task.assigner_id, @task.executor_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end     
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

factory

```
factory :task do
  content { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  deadline { Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now + 2, DateTime.now + 3) }
  association :executor, factory: :user
  association :assigner, factory: :user
end
```

tasks_controller_spec.rb

```
.....
before(:each) do
    login_user
end

describe "POST create" do

  context "with valid attributes" do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }
    let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
    let!(:profile_2) { create(:profile, user: user) }
    let!(:conversation) { create(:conversation, sender: @user, recipient: user) }
    subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, user_id: @user.id, task: attributes_for(:task, assigner: @user, executor: user) }

    it "saves the new task in the db" do
      expect{ create_action }.to change{ Task.count }.by(1)
    end

    it "responds with success" do
      create_action
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems in controller spec it's not enough to define task params like `assigner: @user`, so I had to change

```
subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, user_id: @user.id, task: attributes_for(:task, assigner: @user, executor: user) }
```

to

```
subject(:create_action) { xhr :post, :create, user_id: @user.id, task: attributes_for(:task, assigner_id: @user.id, executor_id: user.id) }
```